# Can't clear Gatsby static site cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, service-worker, gatsby

I have a website which was using gatsbyJS (React framework for static sites)

Now I have moved the site to a CMS (WordPress) but because we have used gatsbyJS initially on the same domain, it's showing old cached files that gatsby has built.

we are not able to access the new website on browsers where someone has initially opened the gatsby site, as its just showing the cached files.

From my initial search I came to know following things:

1. GatsbyJS is optimized for [offline access](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2880) using `service workers`.
2. To invalidate the service workers, I need to again server the GatsbyJS static site after adding some script so that when someone visits the site, service workers gets invalidated.
3. I can't control service workers otherwise.

I can't go back to initial site as that's already been published and people are looking at it but there are many other people who are still seeing the broken gatsby site.

any solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to add a script to the new site that removes all service workers, if there are any:

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
      for (let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister();
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

If this is not sufficient in your case, check out [self-destroying-sw](https://github.com/NekR/self-destroying-sw#readme):

> 1. Remove everything about your previous ServiceWorker (registration/uninstallation code, ServiceWorker file)
> 2. Create a file with the same name as your previous ServiceWorker and put it in the same place where your previous ServiceWorker was
> 3. Put following code into the file:
>
>    ```
>    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
>      self.skipWaiting();
>    });
>
>    self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
>      self.registration.unregister()
>        .then(function() {
>          return self.clients.matchAll();
>        })
>        .then(function(clients) {
>          clients.forEach(client => client.navigate(client.url))
>        });
>    });
>    ```
> 4. Deploy your project!

Comment: I have tried this before as well but it didn't work. Seems to me like the browser isn't making any call to server.

Comment: @Deepakjha Updated my answer. If this doesn't fix it you'll probably need to wait until the cache expires on people's machines.

Comment: I am not sure was it because of expiry of cache on its own or because of this script but some of the systems where there were caching issues are now working fine.
I just added the script in the root and included it in header.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using Gatsby you can use the official [Gatsby Browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onServiceWorkerUpdateReady) to trigger an update to the service worker.

In Gatsby, service workers are programmed to update while navigating. The problem is that when a user visits home and does not navigate any further no update will be visible. If you want the page to refresh automatically on first visit and invalidate the old cache, you need to trigger it.

If you have `gatsby-plugin-offline` in your `gatsby-config.js`, add this line to your `gatsby-browser.js`

```
// trigger an immediate page refresh when an update is found
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => window.location.reload();
```

Here some [background information](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9087) about this issue from the official github repository.